# UITableView scroll speed after frame resize

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UITableView which covers half of the screen in iPad portrait mode. Whenever I click, expand button which calculates and animates the tableview's superview's frame to cover the whole screen, scrolling becomes very messy and flickering even with a single row. Especially bounce animation seems to be longer. TableView is masked with autoresizeheight. After I restore superview's frame, tableview scrolling becomes smoother again. Are there any relation between tableview's initial frame and the scrolling speed? What are the possible root causes for this kind of behavior?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your scenario but I have given you the +1 vote because I have seen odd behavior when animating transitions on a table view.  My unfortunate solution was to cut off the animation and just opt for an immediate UI update.  I'm not suggesting you do the same but I am curious why the UITableView can be difficult to transition in size or (in my case) from within a Pop-Over view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you inserted the resize inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, so it sets the size tableview every time you scroll. I inserted this code snippet inside a check in viewDidLoad, then the size will be set just once at the beginning and everything works.

```
CGPoint tvFrameO = _TableView.frame.origin;
CGSize tvFrameS = _TableView.frame.size;
float valueToResize = 50.0f;
_TableView.frame = CGRectMake(tvFrameO.x, 
                                     tvFrameO.y, 
                                     tvFrameS.width, 
                                     tvFrameS.height + valueToResize);
```